# Why doesn't the key to switch on all scene layers work on linux

Tags: interface, shortcut

Since I use Blender (2.12), the key on a german keyboard on windows to switch on all layers is <kbd>Ö</kbd> (right to the <kbd>L</kbd>).

In Ubuntu it doesn't work and never has for me and I'm using Linux for at least 6 years now.

Is there any reason behind that? After some research it seems as if Blender didn't recognize a lot of special keys (mostly keys between the letter keys and return) for keyboard shortcuts while it easily manages to do so for typing text. They don't work in the game engine's keyboard sensors as well. I can't imagine this to be a bug since it's been like that forever. Is there a setting I miss?

Here's a list of keys that Blender does recognize when typing text and completely ignores for shortcuts:
Everything horizontally between

<kbd>L</kbd> and <kbd>Return</kbd>,

<kbd>P</kbd> and <kbd>Return</kbd>,

<kbd>0</kbd> and <kbd>Back Space</kbd>,

the key to the left of <kbd>Y</kbd>

as well as the key to the left of <kbd>1</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

Is your keymapping set correctly in your Ubuntu conifg? On a QWERTY keyboard, the default for enabling all layers is backtick (<kbd>`</kbd>... it's the top-left key, to the left of <kbd>1</kbd>). Does that work for you?

Comment: All typing works correctly, so it's hard to imagine it to be a qwerty or qwertz problem. While I can type a ' in the text buttons or a text object, I cannot do so in the keyboard shortcut configuration or a keyboard sensor. On a german keyboard, left to the 1 is ^ and ° and these do nothing.

Comment: Then the problem is likely that you don't have an easy way to type the backtick. In this case, you might be best off remapping the hotkey.

Comment: I made the question more specific. In a text field it's perfectly possible to type anything.

Comment: @Haunt_House this might be a problem on your end then. All is fine for me on Ubuntu.

Comment: Fascinating, since I experienced it through ubuntu 8 to 12 and different PCs. Do you suggest I'm cursed? (:

Comment: @Haunt_House possibly.. or "haunted" ;). I'm running 13.04, it might be mapped to something else, not sure? I had a problem where `Ctrl + Alt + 0` was set to minimize the window.

Comment: Erm, how can nine keys be mapped to not be available as shortcuts? Nothing happens if I press the keys for shortcuts or keyboard sensors. At the same time, the very same keys work fine in a text button. This was already the case pre 2.5, at least for 'all layers'

Comment: I'm not sure what ubuntu includes but I use xfce4 and the keyboard layout options have a few German variations available (I believe they are xorg defaults) that include "eliminate dead keys" in the layout name.